# Versioning an API deployed with SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I've deployed the v1 of an API using SAM. The stack is API Gateway, Lambda, and DynamoDB table.

The Lambda function is versioned via the `AutoPublishAlias` property. The alias name is "Live". Every time I deploy a new release of v1, I get a new Lambda version and the "Live" alias is changed to point to the new release, for example:

**Before release:**

```
Lambda version:
              3 <--- Alias: Live <--- v1 API
              2
              1
```

**After release:**

```
Lambda version:
              4 <--- Alias: Live <--- v1 API
              3
              2
              1
```

Now I want to deploy v2 but keep the v1 deployed.

I've considered the approach of modifying my swagger to create paths with /v1 and /v2 base paths. I'd also create a "v1" alias pointing to the last release of v1, and use that alias for the /v1 API, for example:

```
Lambda version:
              5 <--- Alias: Live <--- v2 API
              4 <--- Alias: v1   <--- v1 API
              3
              2
              1
```

Then `AutoPublishAlias` would continue to move the "Live" alias on each new release, but the "v1" alias would be kept where it was, for example:

**New v2 release**

```
Lambda version:
              6 <--- Alias: Live <--- v2 API
              5
              4 <--- Alias: v1   <--- v1 API
              3
              2
              1
```

This seems rationale with the exception that making a bug fix to v1 would be difficult. I'm surprised I haven't found any discussion of API versioning (not Lambda versioning) with SAM on the internet. Is there a convention for handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a convention, everyone does their own thing that suits their needs.

One thing you could do is to add a [`Lambda Alias`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-alias.html) resource to your SAM template and manually pin the v1 to the version 4 of your function:

```
MyLambdaV1Version:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !Ref MyLambda
    FunctionVersion: 4
    Name: v1
```

However, you correctly point out that pushing a bugfix release to v1 would be problematic. I would recommend splitting the v1 and v2 into independent Cloudformation stacks. Seems like it might be feasible since your functions are behind an API Gateway and, I'm assuming, further development of v1 is frozen, besides the mentioned bugfix releases.

Comment: The separate CloudFormation approach sounds decent. I'd have to add a version suffix to all of my resources, which kind of sucks. The v2 API would also have a different base URL, which means I'd have to stick something in front to correctly route v1 and v2 requests. Do you know if Amazon offers some kind of routing service like that?

Comment: There's Application load balancer, but I don't know if it can be configured for your purpose. You can configure the API Gateway to do path based routing, so you could have /v1/ and /v2/ handled by different Lambdas. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like I need to register a domain name (which I really should do anyway) and then have the Lambdas bound to that domain with different paths. Thanks for your help.